# Superscript in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get superscript working in php. I am replacing the tag  with a superscript digit as shown below in the script. The output I get is `OÂ²` instead of getting `O²`. How do I fix this issue?

```
<?php 
$a = "O<sup>2</sup>";
$a = str_replace("<sup>2</sup>", "²", $a);
...
...
?>
```

I am adding the value of $a manually in the script here but I am receiving the value as a POST `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"` from external application. Basically:

```
    $a = htmlspecialchars_decode($POST['myValue'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $a = utf8_decode($a);
    $a = str_replace("<sup>2</sup>", "²", $a);
```

I even tried adding `php header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');` in the header of the php script but still no luck.

Comment: This might be a [UTF-8 All the way through problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Anyone looking for the answer, the answer is to add utf-decode. Such that ```$a= str_replace("<sup>2</sup>", utf8_decode("²"), $a);```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **UTF-8** charset somewhere in your web page.

This example will display `O²`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Super</title>
</head>
<body>
O²
</body>
</html>
```

But if I remove `<meta charset="UTF-8">` it will show `OÂ²` in the browser :)

Comment: I tried adding ```header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');``` in php but still I am facing the same issue. I know it works in HTML perfectly, but in php it is causing this issue.

Comment: You can set the charset using an http header. Put this at the begining of your script `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: You an also set charset inside `php.ini`. Add this `default_charset = "UTF-8"`